# How can I swap a section of a row with another within an array?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, swap, genetic-algorithm, memory-efficient

I am in the process of coding a simple [Genetic Algorithm](http://www.obitko.com/tutorials/genetic-algorithms/) (GA). There are probably countless areas where I have unnecessarily used a [for](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/for.html) loop. I would like some tips on how to be more MATLAB efficient as well as an answer to my question. As far as I can tell I have succeeded but I am not sure. The area which this code defines is single-point [crossover](http://www.obitko.com/tutorials/genetic-algorithms/crossover-mutation.php)

Here is what I have tried...

```
crossPoints=randi([1 24],popSize/2,1);

for popNo=2:2:popSize
    isolate=chromoParent(popNo-1:popNo,crossPoints(popNo/2,1)+1:end);
    isolate([1 2],:)=isolate([2 1],:);
    chromoParent(popNo-1:popNo,crossPoints(popNo/2,1)+1:end)=isolate;
end

chromoChild=chromoParent;
```

- where, 'crossPoints' is the point at which single point crossover
  between two binary encoded [chromosomes](http://www.obitko.com/tutorials/genetic-algorithms/encoding.php) is required.
- 'popSize' is the size of the [population](http://www.obitko.com/tutorials/genetic-algorithms/ga-basic-description.php), required by my code to
  be an even number
- 'isolate' defines the sections of 2 rows which are required to be swapped
  with each other
- 'chromoParent' is the initial population which is required to be
  changed by single-point crossover
- 'chromoChild' is the resulting population
- Both 'chromoParent' and 'chromoChild' are represented by an array of
  size, popSize x 25 binary characters

Can you spot an error in the way I am thinking about this problem? What's the most efficient way (in computational time) to achieve the same thing? It would help if you could be as broad as possible so that I could begin applying the principles I learn here to the rest of my code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine. If you want, you can reduce the instructions in the loop to a single line by some very simple indexing:

```
chromoParent(   popNo-1:popNo,   crossPoints(popNo/2,1)+1:end) = ...
   chromoParent(popNo:-1:popNo-1,crossPoints(popNo/2,1)+1:end);
```

This may be marginally faster, but as with any optimization, you should profile it first (My guess is that these line contribute very little to the overall CPU time).

Comment: Not sure on what you mean by 'you should profile it first'. If it's a simple concept could you let me know? Or if it's more involved, maybe you could point me to a good resource. Thank you.

Comment: @DeanKayton: When you profile a code, you measure execution time per line, which allows you to identify bottlenecks in your code. [Here's the documentation link to Matlab's profiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html)